# Creating a Domain Class with Some Smarts

Tags: mongodb, grails

So I have a schema that is well defined. The datastorage that backs it will allow for this request. (MongoDB).

Lets say I have a Users class:

```
class User
  emailAddress
  name
```

If I'm merging in data from another source (lets say a map/params, and I can properly identify the source.) My intention is to put the unused properties in a structure within the User class.

For example: If I'm importing a User from facebook, they're going to have all kinds of properties outside just the emailAddress, or the name. BUt I don't know how to deal with those yet.

My question is: How would I design a domain class so that it can handle all of this on the creation of the object? (I'm willing to put a tracer property in to signify the source) [I.e. adding [source: Facebook]]

The outputting class would look, and be serialized as such:

The info coming back from Facebook would be [name: Jim, email: bo@jim.com, friends:1000, level:42]. The resulting class would be:

```
class User
   emailAddress : bo@jim.com
   name: Jim
   extraProperties: [Facebook, [friends:1000, level:42]]
```

What is the best way of going about this? Would it break the domain class model? Is expando something that would work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to design your domain class would be to look into saving the additional user's properties (extraProperties) as a serialised 'document' type object. If you were to convert the sample Map you have into say, JSON/GSON or XML ([Converters](https://grails.org/wiki/converters%20reference)) and save this to your database as a document / large nvarchar, you then have the flexibility of different properties for each user source.

You could then add custom getters and setters to your domain object which would convert / slurp the document, and present it as a map to your controllers/services

```
String extraProperties

def setExtraProperties(def properties){
    this.extraProperties = (properties as JSON)?.toString()
}

def getExtraPropertiesMap() {
    def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
    def extraProps = jsonSlurper.parseText(this.extraProperties)

    return extraProps  //you can then access this using map syntax, eg. extraProps.Facebook.friends
}
```